# Suggestion for notifications: Don't un-highlight any until clicked. Make it an option?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'd like for my notifications to stay unread until I click them. e.g., if I have 10 notifications, clicking on the notification icon will mark all as read/seen. I'd rather click on them, so that if I have 10 notifications, then clicking on one will reduce it to 9, and only unmark the one I clicked.